# Insert XAML inside Frame programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I wish to insert XAML code into a XAML `Frame`, using C#, but I'm not sure how one would go about doing this? I'll provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

XAML Sample:

```
 <Frame x:Name="INPUT"/>
```

C# Sample:

```
 var lines = File.ReadLines("example.txt");
 foreach(var line in lines)
 {
     string content = line
     INPUT.Content = //XAML TEMPLATE
 }
```

So for each line I wish to insert a template containing unique values based upon the line used, so if lines are equal to 3, then insert 3 XAML templates into the `Frame`.

Basic example of template:

```
<Label Content=content />
```

Expected output would then be that the `Frame` has 3 of

```
<Label Content=content />
```

Basically producing 3 labels containing the string from current line.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ItemsControl with an appropriate `ItemTemplate`, which contains a Label, or better a TextBlock:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Assign an IEnumerable to its `ItemsSource` property:

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = File.ReadLines("example.txt");
```